# Filtering in another component in vue.js

Tags: vuejs2

I have 2 components. In first component there are some checkboxes. In second component some values will
be displayed after filtration based on values of checkboxes.(I did this portion using this code `EventBus.$on('change',this.formated);`)

But initially all values should displayed when the page loads. How can I display all the values initially ? I tried several
ways like using watch:,computed: etc. I tried with below code

```
watch: {
            values: function() {

                EventBus.$on('change',this.formated);

                return this.applicants
            }
        },
```

Comment: Please provide some code.

Comment: Thanks @Pradeepb for your help. I provided some code. Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at vue lifecycle hooks,  like `created(),  beforeMount(), mounted()` etc.  https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Options-Lifecycle-Hooks  You will need to use one of these functions to get your values before the component rendering is complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it with relevant **method**

First, bind the list of applicants

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="applicant in applicants">
    {{ applicant.name }}
    <input type="checkbox" v-model="applicant.isChecked">
  </li>
</ul>
```

Second, define the DOM element which holds your filtered list:

```
<ul>
<li v-for="applicant in pick_applicants(applicants)" class="list-group-item">
                                {{applicant.name}}
</li>
</ul>
```

Then implement the following logic with Vue.js

```
const myVue = new Vue ({
el = "#app",
data: {
   applicants: [
       { id: '1', name: 'aaa', isChecked: '0'},
       { id: '2', name: 'bbb', isChecked: '0'},
        ] /* checkboxes */
},
methods: {
   pick_applicants: function(applicants) {
   self = this;
   return this.applicants
                .filter(function (applicant) {
                     return (self.applicant.isChecked == 1) /* returns only applicants with checked checkbox */
                            }
                }
        }
   }
})
```